# How to check a type for mutability

Tags: types, julia, mutable

Is there a way to check if a type is mutable or immutable? Can this check be done at compile-time (i.e. have branches `if ismutable(T)` compile away to just use the codepath for either mutability or immutability)?

Comment: The `DataType` type has a `mutable` field which does what you ask. Or you could call `isimmutable()` with an instance of that type if you have one. Did you want something more advanced than this? (e.g. affirming immutable contents as well?)

Comment: I didn't know about `isimmutable()` because, well, I checked `?ismutable` for the same reason you check `?isempty` and not `?isnotempty`. I think that should be changed in Base. Even then, Base's answer does a runtime check. @Ismael's answer with the edit for `@pure`, you can check with `@code_llvm` that `is_mutable(x)` compiles the function either just be `1` or `0`, meaning that it can be used to compile away the wrong branches. That is what I need.

Comment: Yeah, I thought `isimmutable` was a bit weird way of doing it too to be honest. That and, not that making an `ismutable` function from that is nontrivial, but it's a bit odd that `ismutable` does not exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DataTypes` have a `mutable` field, so you can define `is_mutable` and `is_immutable` using that, since doing that instead of accessing that field directly is more Julian.

Using Julia version **0.5.0**:

```rb
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  By greedy hackers for greedy hackers.
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _' |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.5.0 (2016-09-19 18:14 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

---

```rb
julia> DataType.    # <TAB> to auto complete
abstract         hastypevars       instance          layout            llvm::StructType  name              parameters        super             uid
depth            haswildcard       isleaftype        llvm::DIType      mutable           ninitialized      size              types

julia> is_mutable(x::DataType) = x.mutable
is_mutable (generic function with 1 method)

julia> is_mutable(x) = is_mutable(typeof(x))
is_mutable (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> is_immutable(x) = !is_mutable(x)
is_immutable (generic function with 1 method)
```

Create a `type` and an `immutable` and instances for both of them:

```rb
julia> type Foo end

julia> f = Foo()
Foo()

julia> immutable Bar end

julia> b = Bar()
Bar()
```

Check for mutability:

```rb
julia> is_mutable(Foo), is_mutable(f)
(true,true)

julia> is_mutable(Bar), is_mutable(b)
(false,false)
```

Check for immutability:

```rb
julia> is_immutable(Foo), is_immutable(f)
(false,false)

julia> is_immutable(Bar), is_immutable(b)
(true,true)
```

For performance, also consider declaring these functions as `@pure`:

```rb
Base.@pure is_mutable(x::DataType) = x.mutable
```

Comment: Defining an `is_immutable` function which behaves differently from the built-in `isimmutable` -- so that `isimmutable(Bar)` gives false but `is_immutable(Bar)` gives true -- seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @DSM I didn't know of `isimmutable`, could you please, put that in an answer? You are correct, that it's a bad idea, because of the inconsistency, yet I think `isimmutable(Bar)` should be also `true` not `false`!

Comment: Well, `isimmutable` is doing something different-- the object Bar it's passed is as valid a value as any other, and *it's* mutable.  (The code is `isimmutable(x::ANY) = (@_pure_meta; (isa(x,Tuple) || !typeof(x).mutable))`.)

Comment: I do like **more** how my functions behave, also there isn't a `Base.ismutable` which is inconsistent IMO.

Comment: Ok, if you don't post an answer yourself, I will just update my own with your comments, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Well, from a documentation / disambiguation / code clarity point of view, I agree with DSM, that perhaps your function should at least be called `isimmutabletype` rather than `isimmutable`, since DataType instances are mutable and something like `isimmutable(String)` should most definitely return false (whereas `isimmutabletype(String)` should return true).

Answer (score 2):

As of julia 1.7 there is a new standard library function `ismutabletype`. If your really want `ismutable` to work on types, you can add another method for  it like so:

```
function ismutable(t::Type) ::Bool
    return ismutabletype(t)
end
```

Usage:

```
mutable struct MutableType end
struct ImmutableType end

mutable_instance = MutableType()
immutable_instance = ImmutableType()

ismutable(mutable_instance) # true
ismutable(typeof(mutable_instance)) # true
ismutable(immutable_instance) # false
ismutable(typeof(immutable_instance)) # false
```

I would just recommend using `Base.ismutabletype` to begin with, adding methods to standard library functions isn't recommended in most scenarios